# Hex Value Find with C#

Tags: c#, search, hex

I'm trying to search for an hex value inside a file, if that value is present I need to copy 16 bytes of `char` from that found position. I'm trying to do the same in C#.

Please find my tried code below, correction will be greatly appreciated.

```
BinaryReader bw = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(filepath));
byte[] bc = { 0xa0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03 };
for (int i = 0; i < br.BaseStream.Length-10;i++)
{

if (bw.ReadUInt32() == 0xa00003)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found @ {0}", i);

}

bw.Close();
```

I"m getting an error as follows:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.EndOfStreamException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.

Comment: What do you mean by "16 bytes of char"? Characters and bytes are very different, and you need to know *exactly* what you want. I suspect your error is because you're reading 4 bytes at a time, but reading (length-in-byte - 10) times.

Comment: String which contains 16 char

Comment: Ah, well that could be more than 16 bytes... and you need to know what encoding is being used. Do you know that?

Comment: I need to get only 16 bytes, and display it as string via console. I don't know

Comment: Well you need to find that out. Are those 16 bytes *actually* text, or do you need to convert them into hex? Is the 4-byte sequence you're looking for definitely on a 4-byte boundary?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact that your `for` loop has step equal to 1 and you are reading 4 bytes at a time. After reading, the Stream position is advanced by 4. Change your `for` loop to the following one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < br.BaseStream.Length - 10; i += 4)
{
    //...
}
```

EDIT:

If you want to search at every position without skipping 4 bytes every time, use the following code:

```
    Stream f = File.OpenRead(fileName);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(f);
    for (int i = 0; i < f.Length - 10; i++)
    {
        f.Seek(i, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        if (br.ReadUInt32() == 0xa00003)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found @ {0}", i);
        }
    }
    br.Close();
```

Comment: In the edited version, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: At what step do you get the error? What is the "edited version"? You can append your new version to the initial post.

Comment: Let me redefined my question. Step1. I'm searching for an signature hex value which is 0x030000A0. I need to search for it in a file. Step2. If I found I need to seek to that position and extract 16byte string value to console.

Comment: Then `f.Length - 10` should be changed to `f.Length - 16` since you can't read 16 bytes from `f.Length - 10` position.

Comment: First lets sort out the identification of the hex value, and try to position in file, and out the offset in Console.

Comment: Then provide additional info on what code you use and at what step you get an error.

Comment: Search for an hex code, and find the position of the same/

Comment: Do you use the provided source code or the code from your initial question? What does input file contains? At what exact line do you get an error and what error is it?

Comment: I can change my code if needed. I'm searching for an hex code ie., 0xA0000003. I need to locate in which file position the is present.

Comment: You are welcome. Just don't hesitate to make updates to initial questions and provide more details to get an answer fast.